# What could be wrong with my RODBC configuration?

Tags: sql-server, r, osx-yosemite, rodbc, unixodbc

I have been working for several hours at getting RODBC connected to SQL Server 2012 on OSX Yosemite using RODBC and unixodbc. The error I receive in R is quite generic:

```
> odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ISTSQL;UID=sa;PWD=***")
[1] -1
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ISTSQL;UID=sa;PWD=***") : [RODBC] ERROR: state ±6S, code 20013, message 
2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ISTSQL;UID=sa;PWD=***") : [RODBC] ERROR: state ±6S, code 0, message 
3: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ISTSQL;UID=sa;PWD=***") :
  ODBC connection failed
Warning messages:
1: In strsplit(msgs[i], "\n") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
2: In strsplit(msgs[i], "\n") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

My `/etc/freetds.conf` file includes the following:

```
[ISTSQL]
    host = ip.address
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

My `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file is as follows:

```
[MSSQL]
Description = Microsoft SQL Server driver
Driver      = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.8/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount  = 1
```

And my `/etc/odbc.ini` file is as follows:

```
[ISTSQL]
Driver      = MSSQL
Servername  = ISTSQL
Port        = 1433
Database    = TMS
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

I can connect to the database from the command line via the `tsql` command and the `isql` command. Does anyone have any idea how I might troubleshoot this issue or find more detailed error logs?

Answer (score 2):

For better error messages, note this in `?warning` :

```
Warnings will be truncated to 'getOption("warning.length")'
     characters, default 1000, indicated by '[... truncated]'.
```

That might help you get better info for debugging.

Comment: Thank you , Neal. I have adjusted the warning length accordingly. Unfortunately, the error remains the same. But this is indeed helpful to know.

Comment: If it's still being cut off like that and not showing you the actual error message, that seems like a bug; you may want to email the maintainer about this.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the follow-up. It turns out that I set the `warning.length` in the wrong way. I successfully changed the length as follows: `options(warning.length=5000)`. I confirmed this with `getOption("warning.length")
[1] 5000`. I will update the question with the new details. Thanks again.